# Nvidia Geforce 645m doesn't support second display for GNOME

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with Nvidia Geforce 645M and Intel GPU on the board. So, when I plug second monitor to the laptop, no one display doesn't work, only black screen. But when I turn off GeForce and turn on Intel GPU, second display works.
I don't have this problem in KDE and Unity, but in Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 I have.

Comment: Also, I have installed the latest driver 352.41